# "access denied" when installing Oracle Data Provider for entity framework

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework

I am trying to install Oracle database client 12c release 1 installer. I am installing the .NET data access component for oracle in order to connect to oracle 12c database with entity framework.

When I am in the '*installing product section*', I get this error:

> `Error in writing to file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\\..\..\Xml\Schemas\Oracle.DataAccess.Common.Configuration.Section.xsd'. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\..\..\Xml\Schemas\Oracle.DataAccess.Common.Configuration.Section.xsd (Access is denied)]`

Comment: I'm thinking about the person who hit the -1 !! why?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue, I am facing the same problem. If I click continue it completes the installation, but not sure if that is a good installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the folder read/write -- fixed the problem

Answer (score 11):

Open the path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Xml\
```

Right click on

```
Schemas
```

folder and unset read-only checkbox, run the installer with admin rigths didn't work for me

Answer (score 10):

Even after running as administrator, I still had to locate the file, in my case at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Xml\Schemas" open properties and uncheck read only.  I ended up selecting all the files related to oracle in that directory and doing the same before I was able to get through the install.

Comment: This is more valid answer, than the one above.

Comment: It is looking for "\Common7\Tools\\..\..\Xml\Schema" but your answer is "14.0\Xml\Schemas" how is it relevant?

Comment: I had to set my XML\Schema folder to not be read only and then I double checked the Oracle files inside that folder to make sure they were not read only. Then I tried an install of ODAC again and I was able to install it without any errors this time. However, even though I can get a good Test Connection when I try to make a connection with Entity Framework, the window for the connection wizard just disappears. That's a whole other issue I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It looks simply you don't have access to that given directory.

Please do it all over again with ***Administrator*** rights (use <kbd>right click</kbd> > *Run as administrator*)

Answer (score 1):

You do not uncheck at the folder, but on the specific files. I had to uncheck two files.

- Oracle.DataAccess.Common.Configuration.Section.xsd
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.Configuration.Section.xsd

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

The above worked for me. I was not logged in as administrator (company policy) so I did run Oracle setup.exe as administrator (RMB). This was giving me this error described here.
I was not able to remove from

Oracle.DataAccess.Common.Configuration.Section.xsd
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.Configuration.Section.xsd

READ ONLY attribute, hence I started Windows PowerShell(Admin) and used the command [attrib -R filename] to remove READ ONLY flag.
Then I was able to continue the installation (Retry).